# How to add a blank record/row to a winform gridview?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gridview

This seems simple but not as simple as i thought. I have the add/delete property enabled on the gridview. I used grid.rows.add() but failed to add a blank record. My gridview has a datasource that is a list of objects. How can i insert a new row at the end so that the user can type in the values for a new entry to later be inserted into a database by hitting a button?

```
grid.datasource = list of objects
grid.rows.add() or grid.rows.add(grid.rows.count + 1) (neither works)
```

Am i missing something here? The blank record is used for data to be inserted into the database so the row needs to match the object structure of the other rows also.

a  |  b  |  c
   |     |    <---new row for user to enter data per field; a,b,c

Comment: have you tried to simply add a new element to your `list of objects`?

Comment: bahahaa you sir are brilliant! :P worked like a charm

Comment: Well, I change the comment to answer, so you could accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a new element to your list.
Suppose you have a class named

```
Public Class Person
    Public Name as String
    Public Profession As String
End Class
```

and a List(Of Person)

```
Dim people = new List(Of Person)()
people.Add(new Person With {.Name = "Jon", .Profession="Administrative"})    
people.Add(new Person With {.Name = "Steve", .Profession="Programmer"})
```

and this list is the datasource of your datagrid

```
dgv.DataSource = people
```

You add simply a new element to `people` to have the new row displayed in the grid

```
people.Add(new Person With {.Name = "Mary", .Profession="Boss"})
```